# Using COM dll in a C# Project

Tags: c#, c++, visual-studio, dll, com

I have all COM dll generated from a C++ library project.  I want to use it in my C# project.  I guess, I should import the xxxLib.dll file from the C++ library project, and import it to my C# project.  But this xxxLib.dll is not generated in my C++ project.  But I could see that xxx.dll and xxx.tlb are generated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just register the dll with **[regsvr32](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/regsvr32.mspx)**.

Then add a reference, go to the COM tab, and choose your COM dll.

Comment: Where can I find the COM tab?  U mean in AddReference?

Comment: Yes, from your c# project, right click references, add reference and select the COM tab. It should be listed there once registered with the system.

Comment: Yes I meant add reference, fixed the answer just after post.

Comment: This doesn't necessarily end up in the COM tab.  The Browse tab is best, just pick the .tlb file.  Also avoids having to guess at the auto-generated library name.

Comment: My COM is already working.  It means that, it is already registered right?